# Microsoft Office 365 Developing in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, office365

I want to use Office 365 in my project, but when I try to add, I get this error

[image]

I have a `Xamarin.iOS` project but can't add it..

This [topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/adding-service-to-your-Visual-Studio-project) says that I can use `Xamarin.iOS` also

> The following projet templates support adding Office 365 APIs as a
>   connected service: .NET Windows Store 8.1 Apps .NET Windows Store 8.1
>   Universal Apps .NET Windows Phone 8.1 Apps .NET Windows Phone 8.1
>   Silverlight Apps Windows Forms Applications WPF Applications ASP.NET
>   MVC Web Applications ASP.NET Web Forms Applications Xamarin Android
>   and iOS Applications Multi-device Hybrid (Cordova) Apps

I downloaded and installed [OfficeToolsForVS2013Update1.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx/getinstaller/OfficeToolsForVS2013Update1.appids) and my visual studio version is Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

So what can be problem?

**PS:** I created also a new ios blank project but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, you can add Office 365 as a connected service to iOS "Classic API" project types. Having read the documentation you reference, I agree that it's not specific enough. I have filed a bug against it and hopefully it will be updated soon. Sorry for the confusion!

[image: Class API Project Types]

Comment: ohh thank you for explanation. I was thinking how i can solve it and nobody replied my question..  So how i can get a notification about updating ? And thank you for your reply @JoeMartella :)